# How to get month between two dates

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to get the list of month between two dates say 2013-04-01 AND 2014-03-07
output should be like this

```
month  
April
may
june
.
.
.
March
```

Comment: What with duplicates if a period is bigger? To show them or not? Is an order important?

Comment: Fill in the blanks and you have a list. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: What have you tried? And why not? And do you need only April and March with capitals, or is only your question this bad on quality?

Comment: @MikeW I LOL'd at this one...

Comment: @Mike W every month between this 2013-04-01 to 2014-03-07.

Comment: @Subodh You can just write this list out with a pencil. You're not giving any clues about the source data or what this is used for. Everything is guesswork. This is **not** a real question. Please delete it and re-post it in a proper form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is EASY:

create procedure/function

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `urlopy`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `dowhile`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `dowhile`(dt_start DATE,dt_stop DATE)
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
  `month_name` VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_change` DATE DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  ;  


  SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, dt_start, dt_stop)+1  INTO v1;
  WHILE v1 > -1 DO
    INSERT tmp (SELECT MONTHNAME( ADDDATE(dt_start, INTERVAL v1 MONTH) ),ADDDATE(dt_start, INTERVAL v1 MONTH) );
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM tmp;  
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;  

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

then call it

```
CALL dowhile('2012-05-05', '2013-06-04');
```

Comment: next time You should be more specific